# regex expression to get all digits before full stop

Tags: python

I wish to do as my title said but I cant seem to be able to do it.

```
string = "tex３５９１．４５" #please be aware that my digit is in half-width
text_temp = re.findall("(\d.)", string)
```

My current output is:

```
['３５', '９１', '４５']
```

My expected output is:

```
['3591.'] # with the "." at the end of the integer. No matter how many integer infront of this full stop
```

Comment: There are two things wrong: there is no repetition, only one number will be matched by `\d`. `.` matches all characters you have to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: @KlausD.: Escaping with the backslash is the wrong solution in this particular case - see my comment to ruohola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`:

```
text_temp = re.findall(r"\d+\.", string)
```

since `.` is a special character in regex, which matches any character. Added the `+` also to match 1 or more digits.

Or if you actually are using ['FULLWIDTH FULL STOP' (U+FF0E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0e/index.htm) you can just use the special character in the regex without escaping it:

```
text_temp = re.findall(r"\d+．", string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex along with `re.findall` to get your desired result

```
\d(?=.*?．)
```

will generate individual digits as answer

[Demo in regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/cwpU5D/1)

```
\d+(?=.*?．)
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/cwpU5D/2)

This will generate a bunch of numbers as one string

I used a positive lookahead and a greedy matching to check if there is a full stop after a certain digit and then give output. Hope this helps :).

Comment: This would find any digits, individually, before any full-width full-stop. E.g. for `"３５ times ９１．４５"`, it would give out `３`, `５`, `９` and `１`... OP didn't specifically disallow this scenario, but I can't be confident that this is what they meant.

Comment: @Amadan I agree with what you say. If it is something different, I`ll delete the answer.

Comment: It was just a comment as a warning - but it is a possible interpretation of OP. I would leave it standing until and unless OP clarifies. (I'm ignoring OP's "desired result" as that is not possible using regexp, as regexp can't find in a string something that doesn't exist)

Comment: Its just like what amadan said, the value taken is not 3951. but instead 3, 5,9,1. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @kingkongmanoftheworldinchaos the second regex I gave you will give you an answer like that

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I will try to understand more about regex. I still could not find the "?" and "*" fucntions